# copy contents from folder next to current folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder structure like:

- "C:\Auto Deploy\Auto Upgrade\" (Where the batch file is that I'm running)
- "C:\Auto Deploy\Software\" (where the Highest version on the software I want is and the path is variable so I can't hard code that path in my script)

Basically amongst my other code, at once point I'm checking if a folder isn't empty and contains a directory with a string starting with "2.#" as the %latestdir%. If it's not empty, use that as the %softwarepath% location with the highest directory in there starting with "2.#". I do this by using the code below:

```
>nul 2>nul dir /a-d "%~dp0..\Software\*" /s && (
for /f "tokens=*" %%1 in ('dir /b /ad /on "%~dp0..\Software\2.*"') do (
SET latestdir=%%1
SET softwarepath="%~dp0..\Software"
))
```

Then further down the script I have:

```
ROBOCOPY "%softwarepath%\%latestdir%" "%installpath%" /S
```

However, When I run this I get the message "Deploy\Auto was unexpected at this time.", it's obviously not liking the spaces in the path name where the batch file is running from.

I have tried putting extra "", ``, [ ] and '' around both the " '%~dp0..' " and the " '%softwarepath%'\%latestdir%" but this still happens for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I found out if I changed:

```
SET softwarepath="%~dp0..\Software"
```

for:

```
SET "softwarepath=%~dp0..\Software"
```

it worked.

I moved the " to cover the entire "Vairable=CurrentPath\Folder". Not sure why this was the case though as it was a trial an error attempt, but worked